# Python Pandas: Comparison of Min Max Values Per Group

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have some data like this:

```
              timestamp
patient_id
99          10
99          100
3014        20
3014        200
```

How exactly would one in pandas be able to find the largest, smallest, and average range of timestamps per patient id?

What I'm looking for is to be able to report this:

```
shortest range = 90 (100 - 10)
longest range = 180 (200 - 20)
average range = (180 + 90) / 2 = 135
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Setup

Create dummy DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''99          10
99          100
3014        20
3014        200'''.split('\n')
```

Using two nested list comprehensions, split the rows, then the columns and convert all elements to `int`. Then import into a `DataFrame`.

```
data = [[int(n) for n in item.split()] for item in data]

DF = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['pid', 'timestamp'])
```

As learning exercise, loop through each group (assumes arbitrary number of timestamps per pid, not just two). This is not the solution -- it is just to demonstrate how `groupby` works:

```
for pid, grp in DF.groupby('pid'):
    print(pid, grp.timestamp.min(), grp.timestamp.max())

# Prints:
# (99, 10, 100)
# (3014, 20, 200)
```

### The Solution

The solution is more efficient: get vector of mins and maxs, extract ranges, and then find the min, max, and average of the ranges. The strength of Pandas is that it will operate on any column in the `DataFrame` as a unit, making the calculation on arrays very simple, like this:

```
mins = DF.groupby('pid').timestamp.min()
maxs = DF.groupby('pid').timestamp.max()
ranges = maxs - mins

shortest_range = ranges.min()
longest_range = ranges.max()
average_range = ranges.mean()

print(shortest_range, longest_range, average_range)

# (90, 180, 135.0)
```

Comment: Thank you, just as a follow up, how does, I'm fairly new to pandas, I'm just wondering what data type exactly timestamp is and how you were able to manipulate it as a vector?

Comment: @amchang87 -- in setting up the DataFrame, I made both columns an `int`. Also the vector manipulation is in-built in Pandas; I have added some text to the answer to expand on these points.